# Redirect GitHub project page to a subdomain

Tags: dns, cname, github

I have an organization created in GitHub and I created a project in that organization. Now I can create the site for this project by creating the branch GitHub pages and pushing the HTML files there.

I want to point a subdomain to this GitHub pages site. For example, I have a domain called `testdomain.example` and I want `app.testdomain.example` to point to GitHub pages located at `http://orgname.github.io/app`

I went through the documentation but I can't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect to the level you are talking about. You can CNAME the GitHub pages service, and the project pages (through a GitHub pages branch) will exist under it but DNS is based only on domain name and there isn't an option to target it to what amounts to a sub folder of the site.

The best thing you could do in this instance would be to create a repo `orgname.github.io` and create an index page in that with a prominent link to the GitHub pages sub directory. You could do this with a meta refresh targeting the sub directory but it would have to load to the first page before being refreshed into the new directory.